# git log strange behavior

Tags: git

I just got pretty strange result that I can't explain

I wanted to determine difference between two branches

So i typed

```
git log master..release1
```

And I've got multiple commits, including let's say **aa11bb22cc33**

But then I called

```
git branch --contains aa11bb22cc33
```

And I've got

```
release1
* master
```

How could this happen?!

My git log command by definition should show only those commits that are reachable in release1, but not reachable in master?

I also tried equivalent

```
git log ^master release1
```

with the same strange result.

Please explain if you can how is that possible.

P.S. git 1.8.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking through a few man pages, I think it's something like this: Even though [`man gitrevisions`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions.html) says that `<A>..<B>` is "anything reachable from B but not reachable from A", just like you quoted, this "reachable" is meant in a strict DAG (*directed acyclic graph*) sense (i.e. "reachable from" means "is ancestor of").

Indeed the [`git log` manpage](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) states that `<A>..<B>` "shows only commits **between** the two commits." The latter also concurs with how the dotdot operator was explained to me: "Everything in B that's not also in A" (implying A and B are something like branches, which can "contain" commits).

In the DAG-sense, however, there are no branches, only commits (any branches are only references to commits). So if commit X is "contained in B", it is actually some ancestor of B, or in other words: it's reachable from B -- because in the Git history graph, every commit has relations ("pointers", or arrows in a drawn graph) to its ancestor(s).

Hope this helps.

**Edit:** What I forgot to mention is why your commit shows up in the log but branch --contains shows both master and the other branch. I just thought I did know but turns out i don't after all. If you post a the `git log --oneline --decorate --all` output showing the concerned branches, I might be able to update my answer with a more concrete explanation :)

Comment: ahw crap, i forgot to mention the graph switch. could you post the output of `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all` (sorry for that)

Comment: Updated gist with   git log --oneline --decorate --graph master..1.0 # I did not use --all because in this case I have huge history

Comment: hmm, so i tried around a bit and looked at your log, and I can't explain it right now either. In my own repo, `git branch --contains` works as I would expect... Is your repo public, so I could inspect it directly?

Comment: No, it is our dev private repo. I cannot give you access to it. I have already fixed the issue. But I am still curious how it could be possible